# Xcode не видит Framework с папкой Versions

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему Xcode не видит классы в Framework'ах с папкой Versions? То есть, к примеру, классы лежат в папке Versions/A/Headers. А в корне фреймворка вместо папки Headers - ссылка на неё (Versions/Current/Headers). Если я перенесу классы из папки Versions/A/Headers в папку Headers (предварительно удалив ссылку), то Xcode видит эти классы. Но все фреймворки, которые доводилось использовать, имеют структуру с папкой Versions. Здесь явно что-то не так. Вероятно как-то можно научить Xcode находить классы по ссылке, иначе бы такую структуру не использовали :)

Comment: не надо ничего менять внутри фреймворка - это правильная структура. обычно документация к фреймворкам объясняет как их подключать, если есть какие то дополнительные шаги. Так же попробуйте в build settings вписать путь к хедерам в header search paths

Comment: Вероятно при копировании сломались линуксовские ссылки на файлы

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Сейчас стоит значение HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS = .; Проект создается сторонним фреймворком, так что он туда мог напихать любые значения.

Comment: markov, спасибо, это любопытно. Перекидываю папки с фреймворками через винду (движок под винду) и при копировании вылазит ошибка с шифрованием, может на этом этапе и ломаются линуксовые ссылки :)

Comment: markov, вы были совершенно правы. Ломались ссылки. Большое спасибо!